# su command works without prompting password

Tags: linux, security, redhat, sudo, su

I'm on a RHEL server where the `su` command drops the user into root without prompting for a password. Obviously, this is a pretty big cause for concern which I'd like to fix. I'm not in contact with the previous admin, and he didn't leave any notes on what he did to make this happen.

The user account in question is a member of the sudoers group, and I noticed that the config contains the line `Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`, but I'm not sure if this is related.

How should I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: check for NOPASSWD in sudoers file.

Comment: That was the first thing i checked; the only reference to it was a comment.

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu this is `su` not `sudo`. Anyway, check the `/etc/pam.d/su` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if user root has password set. Try login as a root without pass or check /etc/shadow file.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is the root user having no password. Give root a password

```
passwd root
```